# What would be a good option for a non-slip entryway surface in an anteroom where the door is very nearly flush with the floor?

Tags: floor

Our home has a tile entryway/anteroom. The door to the outside is nearly flush with the floor, If you place and secure 3 post-its (i might be exaggerating a bit here, but it is far less than a centimeter of room) on the ground and open the door, the door starts giving some real resistance when the edge encounters the paper. I have a 1 year old child, and I myself have a minor issue with balance (birth disorder) so when we enter after rain or sleet or snow (Im in Northern Massachusetts) I invariably slip across the floor. Like walking out of a shower with a marble tile floor that doesn't have a mat.

Given all of this, we have not found say a floor mat that wont stop the door from functioning properly. However, I am wondering if anyone has an idea for a solution for an issue like this.

I cam to my own impression after looking at an [old stick-on mouse pad](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0017D5Z40) that maybe theres a 3M device or something that is more like a low profile stickon nonslip surface. Ive seen something similar on say [basement stairs](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01AF8IAJO). Obviously my wife was less than thrilled at having Black sandpaper on the floor being the first thing one sees when entering our home.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Comintern that a non-slip paint or coating seems the most likely answer, at least in the short term.

However, if the tiles are exceptionally smooth resulting in shrugging off paint and coatings, it might be appropriate to remove some of the tile—especially in the door swing area—and replace with a rougher or [textured tile](https://www.shutterstock.com/pic-73987279/stock-photo-rough-texture-floor-tile-great-for-your-home-decoration-isolated.html):

[image]

Tiling is not very hard to do well and is extremely satisfying when done.  If you have not installed tile before, find a handy relative/friend/neighbor to closely supervise your first effort.  That should be good enough that you need do it only once.  Or you could just plunge in and give it a try.  If it doesn't turn out, rip it up and try again; the materials are—usually—inexpensive.  It's not rocket science.

Answer (score 2):

One option may be to use a [non-slip paint additive](https://www.google.com/#q=non+slip+paint+additive) mixed with an epoxy or compatible tile sealant. I've used these on exterior pre-cast concrete stairs before with great results. There are also several brands that are specifically marketed for pool decks that are part of a "coating system" that is designed to be used over tile.  If you have a local pool supplier, they may be a good place to start.

Note - since the tile is already laid, I'd either use a spare (if you have access to one) to test the adhesion or trial it in an inconspicuous place before you go forward with the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

Put in a raised threshold and cut off the bottom of the door to match the threshold  Then replace the existing floor with ceramic tile which has a high coefficient of friction.

Answer (score 0):

What's the flooring?  Wood? Tile? There are sand additives for paint to give it grip... it may not be terribly attractive but you could add it just as well to a clear finish and coat the flooring... say polyurethane or tile sealer.